# How do I get a centred bullet list? With an image for the bullet?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Been trying to work this out for a few hours now to no avail....I really want a bullet list that will work responsively (al browser width) that looks like this...

Basically the whole thing needs to center, you can center text but not the span with the bullet image :-(

[image]

I would obviously 'like' to use a UL/LI. But even without doing it I just cannout fathom how to do it. I haven't even addressed the novices/entrepreneurs bit at the end, assume I can overlay an image? Anyway any advice appreciated. I really need it to scale down for a responsive design too if possible...

EDIT :

I have tried  I tried floating, in-lining, offsetting, using a grid system, nothing.... :-(

EDIT 2:

At the request of nathan I will post one of my solutions...

```
<div class="section group">       

    <div class="col span_1_of_2">
        <p style="float:right;" class="darkGrey">
            <span class="sprite step2"></span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col span_1_of_2">
        <h3 class="darkGrey">We then seek to place the you in our network of organizations who actively recruit developers.</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

^ the above just shoves my tick all the way to the right.....

EDIT 3

I just tried this using an image http://jsfiddle.net/fSSeK/ and it worked however my bullet point is a sprite background image and it doesnt work!

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes I have, I have tried loads of combinations too many to post, I tried floating, in-lining, offsetting, using a grid system.....Im not just asking because I can't be bothered I just really don't have a clue and I have been stuck for hours Nathan :-)....

Comment: Can you show your code with a jsFiddle link?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on the things you ask for

Comment: Please point me in the direction of said tutorials...?.... I can't find even 1! ?....

Comment: Okay nathan I will try my best attempt in a fiddle for you....

Comment: @Exitos To center the image (vertically) or the text (horizontally)? For the first, go back to the "ul > li" method, try removing all list-style in the css, and set the check image as a background. Then, you can easily adjust the position of the background ;)

Comment: Okay chaps I have my answer I was trying to use a <span> with the background in the LI....but the Answer below is what I can use....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use pseudo-element with background image

For a typical list:

```
<ul>
    <li>The first line</li>
    <li>The Second line which is longer</li>
</ul>
```

and use the following **CSS**:

```css
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
ul li {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
ul li:before {
    content: "";
    background: url(http://placehold.it/20x20) left top no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/S2Mvn/

You can use absolute or relative positioning on the `li:before` element if you need more precise alignment.

Answer (score 3):

The exact technique is dependent on exactly what kind of bullet you want to show, but for classic bullets here is an easy way to do it.

You need to remove the bullet from the browser's built-in styles with `list-style-type: none`, then center the text in the list elements horizontally and use the `:before` pseudo-element to insert a bullet before their content. This bullet will be centered.

Sample CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    text-align: center;
}

li:before {
    content: "• "
}
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/nBvWR/)**.

Comment: The same idea works with a background image, so this is pretty versatile.